# Popup form submission in the index page in cakephp 3.5 using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have to create a popup button in each row of the index row and in the popup i have to submit the form. In the below code the popup is opening for each row and also submitting the form but for the each row the same id is updating. I have taken hidden id input field. 
How can i change the id for each row in CakePHP 3.5 using jquery?

```
          <table id="example2" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th><?= __('Actions') ?></th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($purchaseRequisition as $purchaseRequisition): ?>
              <tr class="sentrecord">                               
                <td>
                 <?php 
             echo $this->Html->link(__('', true), array("action"=>"rejectmr"), array("class"=>"overlay fa fa-thumbs-down fa-fw", "title"=>"Reject"));

                    ?>
<div class="dialogModal">
 <!-- the external content is loaded inside this tag -->
            <?php 
       echo $this->Form->create($purchaseRequisition, ['role'=>'form','url' => ['action' => 'rejectmr']]);

           echo $this->Form->input('id',array("class"=>'inputId','label'=>"Rejection Remark",'style'=>'width: 100%;'));

           echo $this->Form->input('manager_rej_remark',array('label'=>"Rejection Remark",'style'=>'width: 100%;'));

          echo $this->Form->button(__('Save'));
          echo $this->Form->end();
           ?>
          <div class="contentWrap"></div>
        </div>
                  </td>
              </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <script>
          $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".sentrecord").each(function(){
           var sentRec = $(this);
     // $(this).find(".checkboxSel").click(function(){

            //prepare the dialog

            //respond to click event on anything with 'overlay' class
            $(this).find(".overlay").click(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();

                $(sentRec).find(".dialogModal").dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    show: {
                        effect: "blind",
                        duration: 500
                        },
                    hide: {
                        effect: "blind",
                        duration: 500
                        },
                    modal: true
                    });             

                var qty = $(sentRec).find("#test").val();
                $(sentRec).find(".inputId").val(qty);
                alert(qty);
                $('.contentWrap').load($(this).attr("href"));  //load content from href of link
              //  $('.dialogModal').dialog('option', 'title', $(this).attr("title"));  //make dialog title that of link
                $('.dialogModal').dialog('open');  //open the dialog
                });


    //  });    

});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

IDs must be unique, you are using the same `dialogModal` ID for all dialog elements, hence when targeting it via jQuery you'll always target the first occourence of that ID.

Use a class instead and target it as a descendant of your `sentrecord` element, eg

```
<div class='modal'><!-- ... --></div>
```

```
sentRec.find('.modal').dialog(/* ... */);
```

And target `contentWrap` similarily, it's a class, not an ID.

Comment: I have made changes in the code but it's not working even now popup is not opening. can you pls review and correct the issue?